# How to convert this pywintypes.datetime variable into yyyymmdd format?

Tags: python, datetime

I have a variable `date_var` with the contents that look like this when I do a `pprint`;

`[pywintypes.datetime(2022, 3, 23, 0, 0, tzinfo=TimeZoneInfo('GMT Standard Time', True))]`

I would like to convert this `pywintypes.datetime` variable into the format `yyyymmdd`. The converted output will be `20220323`.

I am using python 3.9.

Comment: can u give us the code that creates the pywintypes.datetime

Comment: @M.Mevlevi, it was read from a proprietary database. I don't think my code will help because you won't be able to reproduce the same variable. Basically, the variable was created by reading from the proprietary database through win32com.client python module.

Answer (score 0):

I will answer my own question.

I discover `date_var` is `datatime` type. So, to convert it to `yyyymmdd`, the code is `date_var.strftime('%Y%m%d')`.